# Facebook wall post description does not appear on IOS Mobile

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile

I'm using the FB.ui call to generate a Facebook Wall post.  I'm setting a link, caption, and description with the FB.ui call.  The code looks something like this:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'MyName',
    image: 'http://myimage.com',
    link: 'http://mysite.com',
    to: 'A Facebook user ID',
    caption: 'my caption',
    description: 'my description'
},
function(response) {});
```

This appears to work fine: I successfully write the Wall post to the designated user's wall.  It all looks perfect on the web.

But when viewing the wall post on mobile on an IOS device, either through the Facebook app or on a mobile browser, the description does not appear.

This doesn't happen with regular wall posts.  And I've seen some apps post things where everything shows up. But it doesn't appear when posting through my app.

Anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are you saying it looks fine when you post with your app and view on the web? If so, that seems to imply that the create is working but the read isn't returning the description for some reason.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Everything looks fine when the pop-up appears when posting, and everything looks fine when viewing the wall post on the web.  It's only on the mobile device that the description is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a confirmed bug on Facebook.

> Description of feed stories does not appear on m.facebook.com or
>   mobile native Facebook apps
>   http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/255260497908026/

Comment: FB has closed the bug as 'not-a-bug' with no plans to fix.  This is not documented and unacceptable.  I also noticed the 'picture' provided in the Graph API is cropped beyond recognition on mobile.  This is not documented either.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same issue. The facebook apps for both iPhone and Android don't seem to show the value that was posted in the description field but the web ui does seem to include it. Which means viewing a post in a desktop web browser gives you different info than if you view the same post in one of the facebook mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at the html of the post with 'inspect element' from your favourite browser's dev tools. Maybe there's something there the facebook app and mobile browser don't like which the desktop browser you're testing with can handle.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the same problem. My workaround was just to use the Caption instead of the Description, seems to be limited to about 1000 characters. Not ideal, but couldn't find any other workarounds!